# Modify XML File in C++

Tags: c++, xml, file-io, xml-parsing, fileparsing

I want to modify an XML file which has a very complicated structure something like

```
<root>
<a></a>
<b></b>
<c></c>
<d>
   <e>text</e>
   <f>text</f>
<d>
<d>
....
</root>
```

I tried to use tinyxml and it is good but there are some comments in the source xml file that I want to keep so I thought may be dealing with the file as mere text can be a good idea, however the string functions in c++ are crippling me because I'll have to search and replace, any ideas?

Note:There are no attributes in the XML, just values between the tags.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if using a third party library is off the table for parsing but I've been using this [XSD](http://www.codesynthesis.com/products/xsd/) parser which allows you to serialize XML files to memory. You are then free to edit and/or read the values at their node locations and then write the file back out.

This, to me, at least, is significantly simpler than generating a custom parser for each type of XML input.

Comment: I would like to keep it as simple as possible;since all what I need to do is modify some values only. Moreover, I wonder if XSD will allow me to preserve the comments in the file too

Comment: @PokaYoke I *think* it will preserve the comments, I've never tried, but it's a nice little science project for you to try. XSD is very easy to use and you can be up serializing data in less than 10 minutes.

Comment: Which is better in my case do you think, the parser mapping or the tree mapping?

Comment: Honestly it depends on the XML file. The tree parser holds the whole XML in memory. The stream parser is used for larger XML files. I prefer the tree parser.

Comment: @TylerJandreau You might want to mention that Codesynthesis XSD needs an XML Schema as input.